# Rovelli's relativistic phase space

Tags: general-relativity, phase-space

I'm trying to understand the definition of relativistic phase space given by Rovelli in his book [Quantum Gravity](https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B00AKE1R5I/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1). At chapter 3 he states those following definitions

- The relativistic phase space $\Gamma$ is the space of relativistic states - p.107;
- The relativistic phase space $\Gamma$ is the space of orbits of $d\theta$ in $\Sigma$ - p.102;
- The relativistic phase space $\Gamma$ is the space of physical motions (i.e: the space of all solutions of the equations of motion) -p.102;

**relativistic states definition:** he define using the pendulum example: we have the pendulum physical motion given by the evolution equation $f(\alpha,t)=0$ where $\alpha$ is elongation and $t$ is time.  So, $(\alpha,t)$ is just a point in relativistic configuration space $\mathcal{C}$. But, the evolution equation $f$ changes when we disturb the pendulum: so we have two parameters $(A,\phi)$ such that $f(\alpha,t;A,\phi)=\alpha-A\sin{(\omega t+\phi)}$ and we define $(A,\phi)$ as a state.

**orbits definition:** we define a degenerated 2-form on $\mathbb{R}\times T^*\mathcal{C}$ such that $\Sigma$ is the hypersurface which $(d\theta)(X)=0$ and the orbits of $d\theta$ is the integral curves of such $X$ (called the null vector space).

**My question:** Actually there isn't difficult link the last two definitions. My problem is link the first (where $\Gamma$ is space of states) with the others (like where $\Gamma$ is the space of all physical motions).

Also, I'm looking for more about it, but I can't find those definitions in any other book. Therefore, I would also be grateful for new references ! Thanks in advance.